# Superimpose heat maps in one plot in python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I have two 100x100 matrices

```
u[0] and u[1]
```

I've set my values of the two arrays between 0 and 1 to make a heat map using the matplotlib function `pcolormesh`.

I am able to get one heat map by using:

```
 fig1=plt.pcolormesh(u[0], cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

but I want to be able to put my two heat maps on the same figure so I can view them together. To do this, I define a global position for the two arrays which describes the centre of mass of the arrays,

```
cm[0] and cm[1]
```

How can I implement this relative global position of the arrays onto one figure and plot my arrays relative to each other?

for example, if

```
u[0]=np.array(([0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0])) is at cm=[10,20]
u[1]=np.array(([0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0])) is at cm=[40,40]
```

then the plot in mind would be something like this:

[image: example plot]

I thought I could use this:

```
 plt.pcolormesh(u[0], cm[0], cmap=plt.cm.jet)
 plt.pcolormesh(u[1], cm[1], cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

but `plt.pcolormesh` does not take in that many arguments.

Comment: What exactly do you wish to achieve? You can use two subplots side-by-side, by calling `hfig,hax=plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2)`, then `for k in range(2): hax[k].pcolormesh(u[k],cmap='jet')`. If you want them on the same axes: how do you want to show them both?

Comment: Fortunately I left your question opened, so I noticed that you updated it:) Next time, please leave me a comment that you've added some info to make sure I notice it. Those who have commented on your post can be notified in a comment by adding their name with an @ sign before them: @AndrasDeak to notify me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just have to look at [the manual for `pcolormesh`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh) a bit more carefully. You *can* specify in-plane coordinates for `pcolormesh`:

```
pcolormesh(X, Y, C)
```

The manual also hints that you can add one dimensional arrays as `X` and `Y`, so you don't have to mess around with `numpy.meshgrid`.

So you should do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

us = [np.array(([0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0])), np.array(([0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]))]
centers = [[10,20],[40,40]]

plt.figure()
for cm,u in zip(centers,us):
    n,m = u.shape
    X = np.arange(n+1)
    Y = np.arange(m+1)
    # center and shift coordinates
    X = X - n/2.0 + cm[0]
    Y = Y - m/2.0 + cm[1]
    plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,u)
```

Since we constructed the `X` and `Y` data from the indices of the data array, the size of each "heat map" is much smaller than your example figure, but this can trivially be fixed with some scaling of the `X`, `Y` arrays. The result of the above code:

[image: result]