# Python: is it possible to interpolate a matrix in a MATLAB style?

Tags: python, image, matlab, matrix, interpolation

I have difficulty to interpolate a matrix/data frame in python.

Suppose we I have a matrix `M = 3x4` and `x = [1 3 5]`, `y = [0.1 0.4 0.5 0.7]`

This is my way to do interpolate and then plot in Matlab.

```
xq = 1:1:5;
yq = 0.1:0.1:1;
[xq,yq] = meshgrid(xq,yq);
zq = interp2(y,x,M,xq,yq);
figure
h=pcolor(xq,yq,zq)
set(h,'EdgeColor','none')
```

This is a possible way in Python

```
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np

def my_interp(X, Y, Z, x, y, spn=3):
    xs,ys = map(np.array,(x,y))
    z = np.zeros(xs.shape)
    for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(xs,ys)):
        # get the indices of the nearest x,y
        xi = np.argmin(np.abs(X[0,:]-x))
        yi = np.argmin(np.abs(Y[:,0]-y))
        xlo = max(xi-spn, 0)
        ylo = max(yi-spn, 0)
        xhi = min(xi+spn, X[0,:].size)
        yhi = min(yi+spn, Y[:,0].size)
        # make slices of X,Y,Z that are only a few items wide
        nX = X[xlo:xhi, ylo:yhi]
        nY = Y[xlo:xhi, ylo:yhi]
        nZ = Z[xlo:xhi, ylo:yhi]
        intp = interpolate.interp2d(nX, nY, nZ)
        z[i] = intp(x,y)[0]
    return z

zq = my_interp(y, x, M, xq, yq)
```

Comment: Some blatant self-promotion: [interpolation (look for griddata)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643642/scipy-interp2d-bisplrep-unexpected-output-when-given-1d-input/34656728#34656728) and [pcolor(mesh)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162798/superimpose-heat-maps-in-one-plot-in-python/35166749#35166749). The necessary functions are well documented.

Comment: You might describe the process and outcome for those Python folks who aren't conversant with MATLAB functionality.

Comment: Thanks guys...:) I will share my Python code!

Comment: @Prune actually, prepending `np.` `sp.interpolate.` or `plt.` will make this almost 1:1 with numpy. As in `np.meshgrid`, `sp.interpolate.griddata`, `plt.pcolor`. Even `sp.interpolate.interp2d` would work, but it's best avoiding it. Otherwise I fully support your notion, needs more info for general clarity.

Comment: numpy's `np.interp2d` is the equivalent command

Comment: @roadrunner66 numpy doesn't have one in 1.10.1 at least.

Comment: @Andras -- I quite agree; this is why I didn't downvote or vote to close. It's clear to *me*, but the original post excludes some potential contributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, your code is 1:1 translatable to python using the necessary libraries. You need `numpy` for [`linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)/[`meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html), `matplotlib.pyplot` for [`pcolor(mesh)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh), `scipy.interpolate` for [`griddata`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html). I was going to say "[`interp2d` is available but don't use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643642/scipy-interp2d-bisplrep-unexpected-output-when-given-1d-input/34656728#34656728), but it turns out that you need extrapolation outside the convex hull of your input data, so `griddata` won't cut it. Here's a solution with [`interp2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html), but take the results with a grain of salt:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as interp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# input
xv = np.array([1, 3, 5])
yv = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7])
x,y = np.meshgrid(xv,yv)
M = np.random.rand(4,3)

xqv = np.arange(1,6)
yqv = np.arange(0.1,1.1,0.1)
xq,yq = np.meshgrid(xqv,yqv)
zqfun = interp.interp2d(x,y,M)
zq = zqfun(xqv,yqv)

plt.figure()
#h = plt.pcolor(xq,yq,zq)
h = plt.pcolormesh(xq,yq,zq)   # <-- same thing but faster
```

Result(left) compared with your MATLAB original (right; after fixing the order `x,y,M` in `interp2d`):

[image: result] [image: matlab original]

You can see that the results differ at the sides, this is because MATLAB always throws away the last row and column of the data, while matplotlib doesn't.